# How to chain call functions by using a string containing that chain in PHP

Tags: php, call, method-chaining

I have a chain call like so:

```
$object->getUser()->getName();
```

I know that I can use a string to call a function on an object:

```
$functionName = 'getUser';
$object->$functionName() or call_user_func(array($object, functionName))
```

I was wondering if it was possible to do the same for a chain call?
I tried to do:

```
$functionName = 'getUser()->getName';
$object->functionName();
```

But I get an error

> Method name must be a string

I guess this is because the `()` and `->` cannot be interpreted since they are part of a string? Is there any way I can achieve this without having to do:

```
$function1 = getUser;
$function2 = getName;
$object->$function1()->$function2();
```

The aim is to get an array of functions and to chain them, in order to call this chain on the given object, e.g.:

```
$functions = array('getCoordinates', 'getLongitude'); // or any other chain call
$functionNames = implode('()->',$functions);
$object->$functionNames()
```

Comment: In your class method return the current class by doing this `return $this;`'.

Comment: @Voitcus Could you give me an example?

Comment: @Akar I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: Does it have to be a string in this format `'getUser()->getName'`? It'd be pretty darn trivial if you "support" a more neutral format like `getUser.getName`. Would you need to support parameters as well? (If that's the case I'd question whether this whole endeavour is a good idea though.)

Comment: `$functionName = 'getUser()->getName'; eval('$object->'.$functionName.'();');`

Comment: ...or `$output = eval(...` (note the use of `'` quotes around `$object`, so that it is not parsed as a string)

Comment: "I have a very bad feeling about this." - http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f9/Death_star1.png - this idea really stinks of bad code design

Comment: @Mark Yeah... though in something like a templating system this is pretty common and useful.

Comment: @MarkBaker could you please explain your statement? :) why "stinky" and "bad code design"? I am trying to create a generic way of filtering objects in and array. Sometimes this filtering requires a chain call to compare specific fields with a given value.

Comment: In this case you may simply accept a *callback function* to derive the value. That's the most generic way possible without needing to invent a mini-expression language for this purpose yourself, as you're doing.

Comment: @deceze I'm not sure I understand what you mean, would you mind giving a small example? Or explain what you mean by "accept a callback function to derive the value"?

Comment: `myFilterFunc($array, function ($obj) { return $obj->getUser()->getName(); })` – something like this.

Comment: But it is not always `->getUser()->getName()`, as I stated in my post, it could be `->getCoordinates()->getLongitude()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78158/discussion-between-skirato-and-deceze).

Comment: Well, that's what you have the alterable callback function for...!? If you need further details on this you should create a new question with appropriate details.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let's start with a more neutral text format that's easy to handle:

```
$chain = 'getUser.getName';
```

And then simply [reduce](http://php.net/array_reduce) it:

```
$result = array_reduce(explode('.', $chain), function ($obj, $method) {
    return $obj->$method();
}, $object);
```

Note that you could even inspect the `$obj` to figure out whether `$method` is a method or a property or even an array index and `return` the value appropriately. See [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#variables) for inspiration.

Comment: Nice one, but `explode` can use multiple-string as a delimiter, so there is no problem with `->`

Comment: Yes, but the goal is to start from a language-neutral expression, not PHP-code-as-string.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to create a generic way of filtering objects in and array. Sometimes this filtering requires a chain call to compare specific fields with a given value.

I think that instead of inventing new solution you can use existing one like [PropertyAccess Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_access/introduction.html) from Symfony.