# Run method chain from a string value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a question about getting value from running a method from a string. While I am able to handle a single method call from a string I am curious how to call a chain of methods from a string.

For example. $project is an Object.

```
$method1 = "name";
$project->$method1;  // It shows the valid results 

$method2 = "get()->first()->name";
$project->get()->first()-name; // It shows the valid results
$project->$method2; // get a null result
```

Please help to find a way to make the **$method2** work. And what happen if I have params inside those methods?

The reason here is I have made an array of customized methods. It can be run line by line, but I am thinking of a way to turn them into a loop, so it's more efficient. Put the methods in to a file then get values by looping to them.

Array = ["getvalue1()", "getvalue2()",...."getValuen()->anotherMethod()->value"]

Thanks,

Comment: Not really a good idea; but if you have to do something like this, then you could split the string into an array of individual method calls, and iterate over the array calling each in turn

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to chain call functions by using a string containing that chain in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319950/how-to-chain-call-functions-by-using-a-string-containing-that-chain-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want nested try something like this:

```
private function callMethodChain($model, $methodChain)
{
    return array_reduce(explode('->', $methodChain), function($model, $method) {
        return $model->$method;
    }, $model);
}
```

This will go through a chain of method calls as your described. If some of the chain (the last piece) is a property I think I once rigged up the following to handle it:

```
protected function callMethodChain($model, $methodChain)
{
    return array_reduce(explode('->', $methodChain), function($model, $method) {
        try {
            return $model->$method;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $model->$method();
        }
    }, $model);
}
```

If you want to add params try replacing `$model->method` with:

```
call_user_func_array(
        array($project, 'your_method'),
        $params
    );
```

Comment: Thanks @chasenyc. It seems to work with a string like "getMethod1()->getMethod2()". But not the "getMethod1()->getMethod2()->name". It shows an error name() is "Call to undefined method"

Comment: I've added a followup that worked for me to handle both properties and methods. I would also ensure that name is a property on that return from `getMethod2()`

Comment: It's weird when I try this. It shows "Trying to get property of non-object.".

Comment: Try removing the ()'s from the string?

Comment: Hi chasenyc. It works when I change try and catch method.

try {
            return $model->$method();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $model->$method;
        }

Comment: I have another question that how can we put params inside the method with this?

Comment: I've edited the result with a little bit more regarding how you would implement params.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
$method1 = 'name';
$project->{$method1}();
```

Comment: Thanks @LBA. It works. However, with the $method2 = "get()->first()->name". It's hardy be done by this way. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

> Run method from a string value

Use [call_user_func()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php).

[call_user_func_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) suits good if you are passing parameters

```
call_user_func_array(
        array($project, 'your_method'),
        $params
    );
```

**Chain function**

```
function chain_fun($chain,$object)
{
  return array_reduce(explode('->', $chain), function ($obj, $method) { 
   if(preg_match('/[()]/',$method)){
         $method=trim($method,'()');
         return $obj->$method();
   }    
   return $obj->$method;
  }, $object);
 }
```

**Here is test**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ cat test.php 
<?php
class Testclass
{
    private $str;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->str = new StdClass;
    }
    function addA()
    {
        $this->str->a='A';
        return $this;
    }
    function addB()
    {
        $this->str->b='B';
        return $this;
    }
    function get()
    {
        return $this->str;
    }   
}

function chain_fun($chain,$object)
{
  return array_reduce(explode('->', $chain), function ($obj, $method) { 
   if(preg_match('/[()]/',$method)){
    $method=trim($method,'()');
    return $obj->$method();
   }    
   return $obj->$method;
 }, $object);
}


$object = new Testclass();

// Output 1
print_r(chain_fun("addA()->addB()->get()", $object));

// Output 2
echo chain_fun("addA()->addB()->get()->a", $object);


?>
```

**Output**

```
akshay@db-3325:/tmp$ php test.php 
stdClass Object
(
    [a] => A
    [b] => B
)
A
```

Comment: Thanks @Akshay. I didn't try your method yet. The upper suggestion works for me. I will check your later.